# Make variable persist between 2 sessions

Tags: php, drupal-7

I hope I can explain my problem clearly enough, without adding too many details. I have a web site where I am trying to make a variable persist between 2 different sessions. One between the user client and the site and one between an external API service and the site.

Step 1: the user client sends a request to the server using ajax. On the server side this request is handled and if all is well my site sends a request to an external API service. This external service returns **true** if everything checks out and my site sends a success response to the user client side.

Step 2: after a delay (up to 3 mins) the external API service sends a new separate POST request to a custom callback URL on my site. Now the external service is acting client and my site is acting server. In the function that captures this callback I want to save the posted data with the function save_data().

Step 3: the user client sends a second ajax call to check if the external service has posted any data yet. Here I want to use the same function save_data() to retrieve the data saved in step 2.

This is what I have so far...

```
// callback from external service acting as client
function _api_callback() {
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), $assoc = true);
  save_data('test', serialize($data)); // save data from external service
}
```

The function above captures data from the external service and saves it using the function `save_data()`.

```
// ajax call from user client, checking if callback has arrived from external service
function _check_api_callback() {
  $data = save_data('test'); // retrieve data saved during external callback session
  drupal_json_output('data: '.$data);  // debug in console
  drupal_set_message(t("data: ".$data)); // debug info on page reload
}
```

In the function above an ajax call from the client side is captured and the function save_data() is used to retrieve data from the external API service, that was saved earlier.

```
// save data from external service to make it available for user client
function save_data($key, $value = NULL) {
  global $user;
  static $storage;
  if ($value) {
    $storage[$key] = $value;
    $_SESSION['lists'][$key] = $value;
  }
  else if (empty($storage[$key]) && isset($_SESSION['lists'][$key])) {
    $storage[$key] = $_SESSION['lists'][$key];
  }
  return $storage[$key];
}
```

The function above is meant to save data when it's captured from the external API and also to retrieve the data when the user client checks in to see if the external service has sent any data. I found this function [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4851/how-do-i-save-session-data-for-the-anonymous-users).

Problem: the above does not work, nothing is retreived from the function save_data(), so how can I make the data recieved from the external service, available for the second ajax call in step 3 above?

I should mention also that I know for a fact that the 2nd separate callback from the external service really is recieved with a 200 code, checking the access logs on the site.

Comment: Don't rely on sessions for postbacks as they rely on cookies, and I wouldn't trust external services to accept or manage them. Embed a unique ID in the postback URL [or data, if it's permitted by the provider] and use that to correlate the postback to its originating request.

Comment: Or use some caching like `redis`.

Comment: Sammitch: Thanks for the advice. I will read up on how to do that.

Comment: Wouldn't the API service callback and the user have different sessions? I think you really want to store the data in a database of some sort.

Comment: MER: Yes you are right. That is also what the question's title indicate. I was hoping that were some way to avoid the db, and use static session variables instead, but I now realize that i will have to use the db to save and retrieve the callback data from the API service callback. Thanks to you all for commenting.